# Android textview multiline (iterate lines)

Tags: android, textview

I want to create a custom `TextView`, which draws a background behind my text, but it should be possible to have gaps between lines, if I use `LineSpacingExtra`. That's why I need a function which calculate the borders of each line in my `TextView`.

How is it possible to iterate through every line in the `TextView`? My first test was splitting the text after every *space character*, but after in a short test, I realized, that a *-* (minus) could also split lines. Now my idea was to go through every line, but I don't know how to get the from and to character position (or something else).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through every line like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); ++i) {
}
```

See `LinedEditText` in https://github.com/chiuki/advanced-textview for a complete example.